# How can I hide a div only on a specific page? WORDPRESS

Tags: html, css

I have this site :

http://dl.dg-site.com/functionmentes/

I tried this code :

```
body.page.page-id-1632 .title_bar {
    display: none;

}
```

I want to hide `.title_bar` only a specific page.

How can I fix this?
What is wrong in what I wrote?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have linked the correct page then the page id is in fact **1637**

Comment: http://dl.dg-site.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1632&action=edit...here I got page id

Comment: That link requires a log-in. I'm not clear on what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: in that link id find that page ... I Mean.Sorry for my english

Comment: We need a link to that specific page...the **admin** link you are providing is **not** working to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think page id is wrong
Try this

```
.page-id-1637 .title_bar {
    display: none;
}
```